# Splitting Integral into Two Parts

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This question might seem very simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Suppose I have an integral over a square region. I was wondering in which case it would be incorrect to split the integral into two separate subregions.

For example, two triangles:
\begin{equation}
\int_x^{x+\epsilon}\int_x^{x+\epsilon}f(|x_2-x_1|)\;\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2=2\int_x^{x+\epsilon}\int_x^{x_2}f(|x_2-x_1|)\;\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2
\end{equation}

My function in this case is an exponential, but I haven't been getting the same answer after computing the two integrals. I was wondering if maybe the diagonal is giving a non-zero contribution.

Comment: You can only do that if the function has the same value if you interchange the parameters.  (You require symmetry of the field over the two halves of the area, otherwise they will not have the same volume.) Here $f(|x_2-x_1|)=f(|x_1-x_2|)$.

Comment: What exactly is the function you're trying to integrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an integral of a function over a square area: $$\displaystyle\int_a^b\int_a^b z(x,y) \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x$$

You wish to equate this to twice the integral over the triangle of half the area:
$$\displaystyle 2 \int_a^b \int_a^x z(x,y)\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x$$

While, in general, these two are *not* equivalent, equality is assured if we have symmetry. That is: $z(x,y)=z(y,x)$

If your function *is* of the form of $f(|x-y|)$ it *should* be symmetrical.

---

The diagonal will have zero measure unless a step discontinuity is involved.  If the function is continuous over the diagonal then:

$$\int_a^b\int_x^x f(|x+y|)\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x = 0$$

---

For example

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x}^{x+\epsilon}\int_x^{x+\epsilon} {\bf e}^{|x_1-x_2|}\operatorname{d}x_1\operatorname{d}x_2 
& = 
\int_{x}^{x+\epsilon} \left(\int_x^{x_2} {\bf e}^{x_2-x_1}\operatorname{d}x_1 + \int_{x_2}^{x+\epsilon} {\bf e}^{x_1-x_2}\operatorname{d}x_1\right) \operatorname{d}x_2 
\\
 & = \int_x^{x+\epsilon} {\bf e}^{x_2}(-{\bf e}^{-x_2}+{\bf e}^{-x}) + {\bf e}^{-x_2}({\bf e}^{x}{\bf e}^{\epsilon}-{\bf e}^{x_2})\operatorname{d}x_2
\\
 & = \int_x^{x+\epsilon} -2 + {\bf e}^{-x}{\bf e}^{x_2} + {\bf e}^{x}{\bf e}^{\epsilon}{\bf e}^{-x_2}\operatorname{d}x_2
\\
 & = -2 (x+\epsilon-x) + {\bf e}^{-x}({\bf e}^{x}{\bf e}^{\epsilon}-{\bf e}^x) - {\bf e}^{x}{\bf e}^{\epsilon}({\bf e}^{-x}{\bf e}^{-\epsilon}-{\bf e}^{-x})
\\
 & = 2({\bf e}^\epsilon - 1 - \epsilon)
\\[3ex]
2 \int_x^{x+\epsilon} \int_x^{x_2} {\bf e}^{|x_1-x_2|}\operatorname{d}x_1 \operatorname{d}x_2
 & = 2 \int_x^{x+\epsilon} {\bf e}^{x_2} \int_x^{x_2} {\bf e}^{-x_1}\operatorname{d}x_1 \operatorname{d}x_2
\\
 & = 2 \int_x^{x+\epsilon} {\bf e}^{x_2} (-{\bf e}^{-x_2}+{\bf e}^{-x})\operatorname{d} x_2
\\
 & = 2 \int_x^{x+\epsilon} -1 + {\bf e}^{x_2}{\bf e}^{-x}\operatorname{d} x_2
\\
 & = 2 (-(x+\epsilon)+x + {\bf e}^{-x}({\bf e}^{x+\epsilon}-{\bf e}^{x}))
\\
 & = 2 ({\bf e}^{\epsilon}-1-\epsilon)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't think there is a step discontinuity in my function. For example, $\exp(|x_2-x_1|)$ is completely continuous, so it should work right?... Maybe I calculated the integrals wrong, although Mathematica is saying the two integrals are not the same...

Comment: @Atreyu, they are the same $\int\limits_x^{x+\epsilon} \int\limits_x^{x+\epsilon} {\bf e}^{|x_2-x_1|} \operatorname{d} x_1\operatorname{d}x_2 = 2({\bf e}^\epsilon - 1 - \epsilon)$

Comment: Haha, thanks for spelling it out, I should have just done that instead of plugging into Mathematica. The same should be true for a function with integrand $g(\max(x_1,x_2))f(|x_2−x_1|)$ since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are exchanged within both subregions, right?

Comment: @Atreyu. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience